# How to prevent Cross-site Scripting on MVC Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have already applied anti-forgery token and Google Re-captcha. but we need to prevent Cross-site Scripting if any another think please let me know.

example:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken, AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Demo(Register model)
 {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var response = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
                var captchaReponse = ValidateCaptcha(response);
                if (captchaReponse.Item1)
                {
                    //Execute code as requirement
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: you can look for work around AntiXSS nuget package. i heard some time back.

Comment: [A good example](http://www.dotnet-programming.com/post/2015/04/12/How-to-Handle-Cross-Site-Scripting-in-ASPNET-MVC-Application.aspx)  check it out if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use  @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in .cshtml file also.

```html
 @using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
```